# phpWord how to load images using PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, doc, phpword

I'm using the PHPWord library and am having difficulty using the library to read this XML trex

```xml
<mc:AlternateContent>
  <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
    <w:drawing>
        <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251657728" behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1">
          <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0" />
          <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
              <wp:posOffset>-54610</wp:posOffset>
          </wp:positionH>
          <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
              <wp:posOffset>132715</wp:posOffset>
          </wp:positionV>
          <wp:extent cx="5470525" cy="657225" />
          <wp:effectExtent l="6350" t="0" r="0" b="0" />
          <wp:wrapNone />
          <wp:docPr id="2" name="Rectangle 5" />
          <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
              <a:graphicFrameLocks 
              xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" />
          </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphic 
          xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                <wps:wsp>
                    <wps:cNvSpPr>
                      <a:spLocks noChangeArrowheads="1" />
                    </wps:cNvSpPr>
                    <wps:spPr bwMode="auto">
                      <a:xfrm>
                          <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                          <a:ext cx="5470525" cy="657225" />
                      </a:xfrm>
                      <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                          <a:avLst />
                      </a:prstGeom>
                      <a:solidFill>
                          <a:srgbClr val="DBE5F1">
                            <a:alpha val="50000" />
                          </a:srgbClr>
                      </a:solidFill>
                      <a:ln>
                          <a:noFill />
                      </a:ln>
                      <a:extLst>
                          <a:ext uri="{91240B29-F687-4F45-9708-019B960494DF}">
                            <a14:hiddenLine 
                            xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" w="9525">
                                <a:solidFill>
                                  <a:srgbClr val="000000" />
                                </a:solidFill>
                                <a:miter lim="800000" />
                                <a:headEnd />
                                <a:tailEnd />
                            </a14:hiddenLine>
                          </a:ext>
                      </a:extLst>
                    </wps:spPr>
                    <wps:bodyPr rot="0" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" anchor="t" anchorCtr="0" upright="1">
                      <a:noAutofit />
                    </wps:bodyPr>
                </wps:wsp>
              </a:graphicData>
          </a:graphic>
          <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="page">
              <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
          </wp14:sizeRelH>
          <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="page">
              <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>
          </wp14:sizeRelV>
        </wp:anchor>
    </w:drawing>
  </mc:Choice>
  <mc:Fallback>
    <w:pict>
        <v:rect w14:anchorId="3C49E1DC" id="Rectangle 5" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-4.3pt;margin-top:10.45pt;width:430.75pt;height:51.75pt;z-index:-251658752;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page;v-text-anchor:top" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQCH0ufrjAIAABwFAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVG1v2yAQ/j5p/wHxPfWL7CS26lRt00yT&#xA;uq1atx9ADI7RMDAgcbpq/30HJGm6fZmm5YPDwfHcPXfPcXm1HwTaMWO5kg3OLlKMmGwV5XLT4K9f&#xA;VpM5RtYRSYlQkjX4iVl8tXj75nLUNctVrwRlBgGItPWoG9w7p+sksW3PBmIvlGYSDjtlBuLANJuE&#xA;GjIC+iCSPE2nyagM1Ua1zFrYXcZDvAj4Xcda96nrLHNINBhyc+Frwnftv8niktQbQ3TP20Ma5B+y&#xA;GAiXEPQEtSSOoK3hf0ANvDXKqs5dtGpIVNfxlgUOwCZLf2Pz2BPNAhcojtWnMtn/B9t+3D0YxGmD&#xA;c4wkGaBFn6FoRG4EQ6Uvz6htDV6P+sF4glbfq/abRVLd9uDFro1RY88IhaQy75+8uuANC1fRevyg&#xA;KKCTrVOhUvvODB4QaoD2oSFPp4awvUMtbJbFLC3zEqMWzqblLIe1D0Hq421trHvH1ID8osEGcg/o&#xA;ZHdvXXQ9uoTsleB0xYUIhtmsb4VBOwLiWN7class3hW6J3G3TOF3CGmjewhvz3GE9GhSedwYMu4A&#xA;C0jCn3k+QQ3PVZYX6U1eTVbT+WxSrIpyUs3S+STNqptqmhZVsVz99FlkRd1zSpm855IdlZkVf9f5&#xA;w4xETQVtorHBlS9lIH6e/YFW5OvpvhA+dxu4g0EVfGjw/OREat/5O0mBNqkd4SKuk9fph5JBDY7/&#xA;oSpBJ14aUWJrRZ9AJkZBF2FQ4UmBRa/MD4xGGM8G2+9bYhhG4r0EqVVZUfh5DkYBygDDnJ+sz0+I&#xA;bAGqwQ6juLx18Q3YasM3PUSKnZfqGuTZ8aAcL92YFeTtDRjBwODwXPgZP7eD18ujtvgFAAD//wMA&#xA;UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBFxM1S3QAAAAkBAAAPAAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sTI/BasMwDIbvg72D&#xA;UWGX0TozXcmyOKUURmG3pWNnNXZj09gOtttkbz/ttN0k/o9fn+rt7AZ20zHZ4CU8rQpg2ndBWd9L&#xA;+Dy+LUtgKaNXOASvJXzrBNvm/q7GSoXJf+hbm3tGJT5VKMHkPFacp85oh2kVRu0pO4foMNMae64i&#xA;TlTuBi6KYsMdWk8XDI56b3R3aa9OQjJ2Zwc8TOWj2Mcztvb98NVK+bCYd6/Asp7zHwy/+qQODTmd&#xA;wtWrxAYJy3JDpARRvACjvHwWNJwIFOs18Kbm/z9ofgAAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAtoM4&#xA;kv4AAADhAQAAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAI&#xA;AAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC8BAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAI&#xA;AAAAIQCH0ufrjAIAABwFAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4CAABkcnMvZTJvRG9jLnhtbFBLAQItABQA&#xA;BgAIAAAAIQBFxM1S3QAAAAkBAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOYEAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxQSwUG&#xA;AAAAAAQABADzAAAA8AUAAAAA&#xA;" fillcolor="#dbe5f1" stroked="f">
          <v:fill opacity="32896f" />
        </v:rect>
    </w:pict>
  </mc:Fallback>
</mc:AlternateContent>
```

I am using the following code to read the word file

```php
if ($model->getIsNewRecord()) {
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(
        \Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/web/test.docx'
    );
    $htmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
    $model->corpo = $htmlWriter->getContent();
}
```

My problem is how to implement correctly so that the library can read the tag `<w:drawing>`, and I was analyzing the xml and I saw something that may be an image I'm not sure, the tag is `<w:pict> <v:rect>`

```xml
<w:pict>
    <v:rect w14:anchorId="3C49E1DC" id="Rectangle 5" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-4.3pt;margin-top:10.45pt;width:430.75pt;height:51.75pt;z-index:-251658752;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page;v-text-anchor:top" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQCH0ufrjAIAABwFAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVG1v2yAQ/j5p/wHxPfWL7CS26lRt00yT&#xA;uq1atx9ADI7RMDAgcbpq/30HJGm6fZmm5YPDwfHcPXfPcXm1HwTaMWO5kg3OLlKMmGwV5XLT4K9f&#xA;VpM5RtYRSYlQkjX4iVl8tXj75nLUNctVrwRlBgGItPWoG9w7p+sksW3PBmIvlGYSDjtlBuLANJuE&#xA;GjIC+iCSPE2nyagM1Ua1zFrYXcZDvAj4Xcda96nrLHNINBhyc+Frwnftv8niktQbQ3TP20Ma5B+y&#xA;GAiXEPQEtSSOoK3hf0ANvDXKqs5dtGpIVNfxlgUOwCZLf2Pz2BPNAhcojtWnMtn/B9t+3D0YxGmD&#xA;c4wkGaBFn6FoRG4EQ6Uvz6htDV6P+sF4glbfq/abRVLd9uDFro1RY88IhaQy75+8uuANC1fRevyg&#xA;KKCTrVOhUvvODB4QaoD2oSFPp4awvUMtbJbFLC3zEqMWzqblLIe1D0Hq421trHvH1ID8osEGcg/o&#xA;ZHdvXXQ9uoTsleB0xYUIhtmsb4VBOwLiWN7class3hW6J3G3TOF3CGmjewhvz3GE9GhSedwYMu4A&#xA;C0jCn3k+QQ3PVZYX6U1eTVbT+WxSrIpyUs3S+STNqptqmhZVsVz99FlkRd1zSpm855IdlZkVf9f5&#xA;w4xETQVtorHBlS9lIH6e/YFW5OvpvhA+dxu4g0EVfGjw/OREat/5O0mBNqkd4SKuk9fph5JBDY7/&#xA;oSpBJ14aUWJrRZ9AJkZBF2FQ4UmBRa/MD4xGGM8G2+9bYhhG4r0EqVVZUfh5DkYBygDDnJ+sz0+I&#xA;bAGqwQ6juLx18Q3YasM3PUSKnZfqGuTZ8aAcL92YFeTtDRjBwODwXPgZP7eD18ujtvgFAAD//wMA&#xA;UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBFxM1S3QAAAAkBAAAPAAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sTI/BasMwDIbvg72D&#xA;UWGX0TozXcmyOKUURmG3pWNnNXZj09gOtttkbz/ttN0k/o9fn+rt7AZ20zHZ4CU8rQpg2ndBWd9L&#xA;+Dy+LUtgKaNXOASvJXzrBNvm/q7GSoXJf+hbm3tGJT5VKMHkPFacp85oh2kVRu0pO4foMNMae64i&#xA;TlTuBi6KYsMdWk8XDI56b3R3aa9OQjJ2Zwc8TOWj2Mcztvb98NVK+bCYd6/Asp7zHwy/+qQODTmd&#xA;wtWrxAYJy3JDpARRvACjvHwWNJwIFOs18Kbm/z9ofgAAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAtoM4&#xA;kv4AAADhAQAAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAI&#xA;AAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC8BAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAI&#xA;AAAAIQCH0ufrjAIAABwFAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4CAABkcnMvZTJvRG9jLnhtbFBLAQItABQA&#xA;BgAIAAAAIQBFxM1S3QAAAAkBAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOYEAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxQSwUG&#xA;AAAAAAQABADzAAAA8AUAAAAA&#xA;" fillcolor="#dbe5f1" stroked="f">
      <v:fill opacity="32896f" />
    </v:rect>
</w:pict>
```

How can you see this excerpt and where I think it is part of the image

And the HTML I'm trying to generate, the two docx images are in the header and footer, and I need these two images to be in html, the text with the styling was working normally, just the image that is not bringing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the PHPWord library is not up to date yet. The current OpenOffice XML defines images as w:drawing but the older versions were w:pict.

I found a pull request that may bring you further:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/1324

Comment: Many thanks for replying, I took a look but I could not locate something clear that could give me the solution of the problem

Comment: I was doing several tests, I suddenly decided to use my own conversion from word to html, and I noticed that reading the header when converting somehow can not find the header, and then it can not find the image in both the header and the footer